# Adjusting font size in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, font-size

I just installed CentOS 6.4 on my laptop and have a quick question. I'm extremely new to Linux and have never really worked on an actual Linux system before. I have some vision issues and am finding the default font size pretty difficult to see. Can anyone tell me how I can adjust the text size? I am using a text-based environment with no graphical desktop installed and like I said, I'm using CentOS 6.4

**update**
For anyone having this same problem, I thought I'd give a quick update to give y'all a couple different options I've discovered on how to fix this. If you're using a graphical desktop, the answer to this post is definitely a quick and easy fix. If you're working in a solely text-based environment, here's a command my professor gave me today that increases the font as well, however, this may only be for that particular session unless you add it to a configuration file, I haven't tested that though.

```
setfont sun12x22
```

Hope that helps anyone having the same issue :-)

Comment: Why the downvotes with no suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find your font options at System -> Preferences -> Fonts menu option

reference link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_CentOS_Desktop_Fonts

Suggestions for text based install https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2932

Comment: I don't have a desktop installed though, it's entirely text based. So how would I get to System -> Preferences etc?

Comment: Sorry missed that, one suggestion is using the command video=640x460 https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2932

Comment: Would I need to reboot after issuing this command! I typed it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Had to dig a little deeper, haven't used centos without desktop before. Try running  sudo update-grub and rebooting. If that doesn't work you will need to edit the grub file at /ect/default/grub  The following link has some detailed instructions on how to do this. It says for console, but grub also assigns the same resolution to the linux text based display. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17027/how-to-set-the-resolution-in-text-consoles-troubleshoot-when-any-vga-fail

Comment: I ended up just re-installing and selected "Desktop" rather than "minimal install" and used your original answer. My eyes thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

install  **yum install epel-release** 
install  **yum -y install terminus***
run command **setfont ter-p18b**

Here 18 is your font size(according to ur need),but this is not permanent,to make it permanent open /etc/rc.local in vi and write the setfont ter-p22b command in last line and save it.

Lastly give it all permissions by **chmod +x /etc/rc.local** and reboot,now it is default.

Word of caution:DO NOT MISHANDLE rc.local